# overriding link style when using bootstrap button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using these tags together

```
<div class ="btn btn-warning offset3 span2" ><%=link_to  "Enter Info", info_path%></div>
```

The outcome is that the link (a) tag overrides the text color property. It doesn't look good on a colored button. So I want to change the properties of a link when used with btn to plain white. Any ideas how to make that happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `div` - you can apply those classes directly to the anchor:

```
<%= link_to "Enter Info", info_path, class: "btn btn-warning offset3 span2" %>
```

That way the link is styled as a button, overriding all default link styles.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this one using the like this:

```
<div class ="btn btn-warning offset3 span2" ><%=link_to  "Enter Info", info_path, :style => "color:#ffffff"%></div>
```